# Find closest object in Java collection

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have a collection with objects that contain certain `int` field.

eg.

```
public class Foo {
    public int field;
}
```

I would like to get an element that has closest value to certain value (eg. `42`).

Is there any neat method from guava to achieve such thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specifically want to use Guava, you can use an `Ordering`:

```
final int target = 42;
Ordering<Foo> ordering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(
    new Function<Foo, Integer>() {
      @Override public Integer apply(Foo foo) {
        return Math.abs(foo.field - target);
      }
    });
```

Now you can simply find the minimum value according to this ordering:

```
Foo closest = ordering.min(iterableOfFoos);
```

However, you can do this with streams in Java 8, as suggested by @wero.

Answer (score 11):

(Not Guava but Java  streams): Use `Stream.min` and a custom comparator:

```
 List<Foo> list = ...
 Foo closest42 = list.stream()
      .min((f1,f2) -> Math.abs(f1.field - 42) - Math.abs(f2.field - 42)));
```

Answer (score 5):

In pure java, you could reduce the collection to its element with the lesser difference to your goal :

```
myFoos.stream()
      .reduce((result, current) -> 
              Math.abs(42 - current.field) < Math.abs(42 - result.field) ? current : result);
```